# Expose parent Polymer element data to a child element

Tags: javascript, polymer

I have following structure:

```
<main-container data-endpoint="/api/allrecent">
  <section>
  <list-container data-source="{{feed.recent}}" data-type="member" data-title="Recent Members"></list-container>
  </section>
</main-container>
```

Where in `main-container.js` I fetch the data with a Promise like:

```
var self = this;
connector.get(this.dataset.endpoint)
.then(function(data) {
  self.feed = JSON.parse(data);
});
```

Now, I'd like to expose `self.feed` to `list-container` as a data-source. Meaning that when Promise gets resolved, it would populate the list-container's content.

I'm just troubled on accessing the feed inside `list-container`. I've read some SO answers and Polymer documentation but haven't found a proper way of achieving this.

The solution is probably simple (like one attribute to bind) but haven't found it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use binding you need a Polymer element or a `<auto-binding>` tag with a model that wraps your `<main-container>` element.

```
<polymer-element name="some-element" attributes="feed">
  <template>
    <main-container data-endpoint="/api/allrecent" feed="{{feed}}">
      <section>
      <list-container data-source="{{feed.recent}}" data-type="member" data-title="Recent Members"></list-container>
      </section>
    </main-container>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
```

Now you can bind an attribute from the `<main-container>` and `<list-container>` to the same attribute in `<some-element>`.

Comment: Yes, the problem seems to be in structure. My `list-container` elements aren't part of the Shadow DOM of `main-container`, but siblings to it. It fixed the problem, partly thanks to your answer. I probably have to extend `main-container` to create e.g. `recent-container` etc.